Model shape inverts when converting from Yolo-NAS to ONNX
I trained a YOLO-NAS model on a custom dataset with dimensions w=640 h=352. The input images are 640x360.
When I do the inference using YOLO-NAS with this code:
prediction = best_model.predict(f'{HOME}/toy_images/resized_frame_0089.png', fuse_model=False)
prediction.show()

It draws a bounding box around my object with accuracy 0.87.
Then, I converted to ONNX using this tutorial and this code:
model = models.get("yolo_nas_s", checkpoint_path=CKPT_PATH, num_classes=1)
# print("Input shape before export:", model.input_shape)

export_result = model.export(
    "toycar_int8.onnx",
    output_predictions_format=DetectionOutputFormatMode.BATCH_FORMAT,
    quantization_mode=ExportQuantizationMode.INT8, # or ExportQuantizationMode.FP16
)

When I run inference on the image,or display the image using the dimensions of my new model:
image = cv2.resize(image, (export_result.input_image_shape[1], export_result.input_image_shape[0]))
image_bchw = np.transpose(np.expand_dims(image, 0), (0, 3, 1, 2))

plt.imshow(image)
print(image.shape)

Suddenly, the image dimensions are inverted. The width is now 360 and the height is 640. I tried to train the model by switching the dimensions around, but then my inference was very wrong. Does anyone know how to fix this?
Suddenly, the image dimensions are inverted. The width is now 360 and the height is 640. I tried to train the model by switching the dimensions around, but then my inference was very wrong. Does anyone know how to fix this?
